# Adjusting the space between the caption below a figure

Tags: spacing, captions

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}   

 \begin{document}
    \begin{example} 
    Consider a random walk on the $n$-cycle. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_n = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \rbrace$ be the set of remainders modulo $n$. Also consider the transition matrix:
    \[
    P(x,y) = 
    \begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x+1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x-1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \]

    The associated Markov chain $X_t$ is called a random walk on the $n$-cycle. The sates can be visualised as equally spaced nodes arranged in a circle(see figure 1.1)
    \end{example}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
        }
        \foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
            \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
        \foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_10$ is periodic, since every step
    goes from an even state to an odd state, or vice-versa. Random
    walk on $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is aperiodic.}
        \label{my:figure}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

now I want to adjust the spacing in the caption in the sense that i want to "push it into the middle", but I don't know how to proceed.

***EDIT***: similar question as above but the caption looks awful in this case, any fixes to stretch it out:

```
\begin{example} Consider the graph $G$ following shown in figure 1.2. The transition matrix of a simple random walk $G$ is 

\begin{equation*}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}[1.25]
    0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \ffigbox[1.1\FBwidth]{%
 \caption{An example of a vertex set $V = \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\rbrace$ with $10$ edges.}
 \label{my:figure}}%
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=1mm},every node/.append style={bn}]
 \path node (1) {1} -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) {2} -- ++(-95:1.75) node (3) {3}
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) {4} -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) {5}
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) {6} ;
 \draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}
\end{example}
```

is there a way to stretch this out into 2 lines at most?

Comment: the code is not compileable

Comment: @AndréC it should work now.

Comment: Your last sentence and the question title don't seem to match. Do you want more vertical space between the figure and the caption, or do you want to adjust the horizontal spacing of the caption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can use the following two lines in your preamble

```
\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth} % <==================================
```

to let the caption use only 80% of textwidth. See the documentation of package `caption` for more possibilitys to manipulate the layout of captions with typing `texdoc caption` on ypur console/terminal.

The complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth} % <==================================

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}   


\begin{document}

\begin{example} 
Consider a random walk on the $n$-cycle. 
Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_n = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \rbrace$ be 
the set of remainders modulo $n$. Also consider the transition matrix:
\[
  P(x,y) = 
  \begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x+1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x-1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    0           & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

The associated Markov chain $X_t$ is called a random walk on the 
$n$-cycle. The sates can be visualised as equally spaced nodes arranged 
in a circle (see figure~\ref{my:figure}). % <==========================
\end{example}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
        }
        \foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
            \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
        \foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_10$ is periodic, since every step
    goes from an even state to an odd state, or vice-versa. Random
    walk on $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is aperiodic.}
  \label{my:figure}
\end{figure}
Text after the figure.
\end{document}
```

gives you the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

## EDIT:

With your second example (after commenting `\ffigbox`, see markings `<======` in code)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{caption} % <================================================
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth} % <==================================

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}   


\begin{document}

\begin{example} 
Consider a random walk on the $n$-cycle. 
Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_n = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \rbrace$ be 
the set of remainders modulo $n$. Also consider the transition matrix:
\[
  P(x,y) = 
  \begin{cases} 
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x+1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x-1\;\; (mod\;n)\\
    0           & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

The associated Markov chain $X_t$ is called a random walk on the 
$n$-cycle. The sates can be visualised as equally spaced nodes arranged 
in a circle (see figure~\ref{my:figure}).
\end{example}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
        }
        \foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
            \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
        \foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
            \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
            \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
        }
        \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_10$ is periodic, since every step
    goes from an even state to an odd state, or vice-versa. Random
    walk on $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is aperiodic.}
  \label{my:figure}
\end{figure}
Text after the figure.

\clearpage
\begin{example} Consider the graph $G$ following shown in figure 1.2. The transition matrix of a simple random walk $G$ is 

\begin{equation*}
P =
\begin{bmatrix}[1.25]
    0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
%\ffigbox[1.1\FBwidth]{% <==============================================
 \caption{An example of a vertex set $V = \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\rbrace$ with $10$ edges.}
 \label{my:figure}%
%}% <===================================================================
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[bn/.style={circle,fill,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily,minimum
size=1mm},every node/.append style={bn}]
 \path node (1) {1} -- ++ (50:2.5) node (2) {2} -- ++(-95:1.75) node (3) {3}
 -- ++(-85:1.75) node (4) {4} -- ++(40:2.75) node (5) {5}
 -- ++ (0,1.75) node (6) {6} ;
 \draw[thick] (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(4)--(1)--(3)--(5)--(2)--(3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting second figure/page:

[image: second page]

Comment: please check my edited question, there is another problem similar to this

Comment: sorry I wasn't available on the weakened. Yes, could you edit your answer adding the extra part, it will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

If I've well understood what you want, this is easy with the `\ffigbox` command from `floatrow`, which gives full control on the caption width:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\usepackage{floatrow}

 \begin{document}

    \begin{example}
    Consider a random walk on the $n$-cycle. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_n = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \rbrace$ be the set of remainders modulo $n$. Also consider the transition matrix:
    \[
    P(x,y) =
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x+1 \pmod n\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } y=x-1\pmod n\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \]

    The associated Markov chain $X_t$ is called a random walk on the $n$-cycle. The states can be visualised as equally spaced nodes arranged in a circle(see figure 1.1)
    \end{example}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \ffigbox[1.1\FBwidth]{%
 \caption{Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_10$ is periodic, since every step
 goes from an even state to an odd state, or vice-versa. Random
 walk on $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is aperiodic.}
 \label{my:figure}}%
 {\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {90,54,...,-234} {
 \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-36}:2);
 }
 \foreach \i in {90,18,...,-198} {
 \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
 }
 \foreach \i in {54,-18,...,-234} {
 \draw[fill=white] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
 }
 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
 \foreach \i in {90,50,...,-230} {
 \draw[ultra thick] (\i:2)--({\i-40}:2);
 \draw[fill=black] (\i:2) circle (1.25mm);
 }
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}}%
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for another solution however Kurt beat you to it!

Comment: I'm not competing :o). The advantage with the solution with `\ffigbox`, from my point of view, is that the caption width can be automatically calculated in function of the figure natural width.

Comment: I understand. the reason I liked Kurt's answer is because for this particular problem I will only need to adjust one number to get my desired output however the drawback is, with another figure, if it doesn't have the same dimensions as the figure above, the caption will be off

Comment: that's where your solution comes in handy I believe.

Comment: To clarify, will your method work for all figures?

Comment: I haven't used it intensively, but I think so (also for all tables with the `\ttabbox` command). That being said, for a single figure, Kurt's solution is quite fine, as it requires only `caption`, which is very often already loaded for a number of reasons. Note that `floatrow` cooperates nicely with `caption`.

Comment: Hey once again, I have another problem similar to this one and I need help on the caption, I will edit this question